# How to use nuget packages not ready for ASP.NET Core 1.0

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I need to use some nuget packages that are not ready for ASP.NET Core 1.0 (final release).

I have read about all possibles configurations... How can I use nuget packages in my project.json?

```
{
  "userSecretsId": "aspnet-WebApplication1-84f1878e-a871-4f80-baca-de15b99a96d9",

  "dependencies": {
    "RestSharp": "105.2.3",
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
    },
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    }
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    },
    "Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net451": { },
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ],
      "dependencies": {

      }
    }
  },


  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "gcServer": true
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

I'm having some errors like this:

> Package Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils 1.0.0-preview2-003121 is not
>   compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package
>   Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils 1.0.0-preview2-003121 supports:
>         - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
>         - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)

I'm using Windows 10 and VS2015 Update 3. Thanks.

Comment: does it work if you change netstandard dependencies to        "dependencies": {

      "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.0"
    }
}? Or, if RestSharp does not support netstandard - remove the netstandard1.6 tfm as you will be only able to target net451

Comment: Can you please add a final project.json as answer please... thanks.

Comment: Not sure if it fixes the issue so I created a gist: https://gist.github.com/moozzyk/35bd9c532c0d1a7edd1f74cf219c88f7#file-gistfile1-txt-L76-L81. If this does not help (as I said I don't know if RestSharp support .NET Core) try commenting out netstandard1.6 entirely and see if it works if you just target `net451`

Comment: @chemitaxis Did you resolve this issue?

Comment: Nop, @RoarG I didnt